# Installing Tensorflow-gpu windows version on a computer with no internet access

Tags: python, tensorflow

First off, I'm a totally newbie when it come to working with Anaconda, python, and other conda packages.  I'm trying to get Tensorflow-gpu installed on a Windows 10 system without Internet access.  I was able to successfully install Anaconda 5.1 (Python 3.6.4) on the system and it works great.  I followed the installation instructions for installing the nvidia cuda drivers and updated drivers.  I'm running into an issue when trying to run pip install tensorflow_gpu-1.9.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl.  It's trying to find additional dependencies in order to complete the install.  This is where my knowledge of configuring anaconda in an offline environment fails.  How do you download all the dependencies of a package from an online system and transfer them to the offline system?  I've searched for documentation on how to perform this task but haven't come across anything streamlining the process.  Would someone happen to know of a guide that steps through this process?

Comment: If the name or the dependency is stated in the error, you can try to download them the same way you downloaded tensorflow.

Comment: Build it from source? But in that case, you need to have some build time dependencies preinstalled. https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources

Comment: Thanks for the reply Daniel,  yes I can do that but I believe there are multiple dependencies that need to be resolved.  Each time you install one it shows another dependency.  I was hoping there was a guide that outlined how to download all the dependencies at one time

Comment: If you have conda on an online machine and use "conda install tensorflow-gpu", it will ask you if you want to continue and list everything that will be upgraded, downgraded and installed.